# How to run f(x) inside a loop which entered by the user

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, variables

I am trying to run a f(x) inside a for loop, when the f(x) will be inserted by the user.
for instance f(x)=(x^2-4)/(x-2). when I entered the the full f(x) inside the loop, it worked. However, when I try to use a variable, it doesn't work.

```
F='(${X}^2-4)/(${X}-2)'
for X in 3 4; do
    echo "${F}" | bc # this doesn't work
    echo "(${X}^2-4)/(${X}-2)" | bc # this one works
done
exit 0
```

Comment: And two tips for getting into `bash` : 1) https://www.shellcheck.net/ does static analysis of your code and will help you avoid many pitfalls by following best practices ; 2) you can use `bash -x yourScript.sh` or add `set -x` in your script to debug `bash` scripts : it will make `bash` display every commands as they are executed but after they are expanded. (also I meant "Text" in my first comment, not "Test" ; can't edit it anymore sadly)

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thanks again. The problem is that I assume that I don't know the f(x) and the user will be prompted by the script to enter it. (i meant to the text solution you proposed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want your users to provide expressions that contain mathematical variables, not `bash` variables, then construct a `bc` command that will value those mathematical variables based on your bash variables before evaluating the function :

```
F='(x^2-4)/(x-2)'
for X in 3 4; do
    echo "x=$X; $F" | bc
done
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/sz9zQ2).

In your code the function variable didn't work because you were defining it enclosed in single-quotes, which meant that the `bash` variables weren't expanded and `bc` received `$X` instead of its value.
Using double-quotes might have worked, but it would have required the `bash` variables to have been defined before the function.

Moreover, expanding user-provided function containing bash variables would have required using `eval` or similar tricks evaluating arbitrary user-provided code which would have been posed a security threat.

Comment: This might be considered as cleaner than my answer, however the question was tagged "bash", so I assume the OP wanted a solution in bash.

Comment: @ternary I don't use any more binaries than OP's code does so I don't think that'd be a problem. Still, the more answers the merrier :)

Comment: Hi Aaron, yes! you are right! I meant in Bash. it works. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The bash shell applies only one variable expansion pass, so X would have to be expanded in a sub-shell. This could be done like this:

```
F='(${X}^2-4)/(${X}-2)'
for X in 3 4; do
    (
        echo "X=${X}"
        echo 'echo "'"${F}"'"|bc'
    )|
    bash
done
```

The security considerations of passing untrusted code into a shell, as they were expressed in the comments, do of course apply. My example hasn't been checked for proper quoting of arbitrary values of F, and should only be seen as a sketch of how it could be done using the shell.

Comment: Hi, also that solution solved the problem. Many thanks!!